# Override favicon.ico with addon in hybris

Tags: favicon, sap-commerce-cloud, add-on

How can I override the **favicon.ico** in the Hybris using an addon?

I tried to overwrite the property `img.favIcon` but it doesn't work

Comment: May I know why you want to change it through addon? find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As favicon.ico is rendered through `master.tag` of the storefront, so it would better you directly change it in the storefront itself, otherwise, you need to create `master.tag` file in your addon and also need to override all its references so it starts pointing to your addon `master.tag` file.

### Simplest

Just override OOTB favicon.ico with your favicon.ico in the storefront. It's done.

---

### Using javascript (Not recommended)

1. Copy your `favicon.ico` at the below-mentioned path in your addon (e.g myaddon)

   `/myaddon/acceleratoraddon/web/webroot/_ui/responsive/common/images/favicon.ico`
2. Add below javascript in your addon js file (e.g. myaddon.js)

   `(function() {
   var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
   link.type = 'image/x-icon';
   link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
   link.href = 'https://www.yoursite.com/_ui/addons/myaddon/responsive/common/images/favicon.ico';
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
   })();`
3. Build and start the server

   `ant all && hybrisserver.bat start`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I copied the Theme.properties to the addons and changed the path